# Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in /my/path

Tags: php, memcached, fatal-error

When I try :

```
$mc= new Memcached();
```

I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in /my/path
```

phpinfo says that /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-memcached.ini is loaded as an additional .ini file.

The content of this file is this one :

```
; uncomment the next line to enable the module
extension=memcached.so
```

dpkg --get-selections | grep memcached

```
libmemcached6                                   install
memcached                                       install
php5-memcached                                  install
```

Kubuntu
Apache 2.0
php 5.4.4-1

Why do I have this fatal error ?

Comment: What exactly phpinfo() tells?
Do you see `memcached support   enabled` section followed by version etc.

Comment: The only occurrence of "memcached" in the phpinfo is in the "Additional .ini files parsed" section .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your comment I don't think you have it installed properly. Make sure you see a see a section in phpinfo() such as:

```
memcached
memcached support   enabled
Version     x.x.x
libmemcached version    x.xx
```

1) Get `libmemcached`

2) Configure the package

3) Make install `sudo make install libmemcached`

4) Try Installing with Install with `sudo pecl install memcached`

5) make sure you have `extension = memcached.so` in your php.ini

Restart Apache

Comment: @Cedric Be careful to add `memcached.so` to the active php.ini