# Php 5.6 Memcached in XAMPP for Windows

Tags: php, symfony, memcached

I'm trying to find a solution for my problem. I downloaded a symfony2 project to localhost. I'm trying to run it, but it gives me an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found
```

I found solutions for Memcache errors, I have memcache installed and I'm running the memcached service too. It needs the memcached, not memcache extension, but I can't find it anywhere for windows. I really need to make this project run. Are there any alternatives? I didn't do anything to this project, I never worked on it, so I don't know the source code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in /my/path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471977/fatal-error-class-memcached-not-found-in-my-path)

Comment: @DipenShah Did I tell you I have WINDOWS installed?

Comment: Well you didn't specify anything. That way the question is too broad in the first place. If not me somebody will flag it.

Comment: @DipenShah did you check the title?

Comment: The info you're giving is too less to debug this kind of error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Please read.

Comment: Check you've got the right memcached DLL (you'll probably need the x86 version rather than x64 with XAMPP) and that you've enabled the extension in php.ini : take a look at the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777857/how-to-install-and-use-memcached-in-windows-for-php

Comment: @CD001 I think even the question is irrelevant for me. I have memcache installed. The memcached extension and memcache extension are 2 separate extensions. The urls given in the correct answer are broken. The error I get is `Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found`. Did you see the 'Memcached' and not 'Memcache'? I have memcache installed. Also, I have the memcached service running. The only thing I need is a working link for the php_memcached.dll. Not the php_memcache.dll. Without the memcached<- (see that 'd'?) php extension the program wont find the Memcached <-('d') class.

Comment: memcache is the required extension to use memcached with PHP but if you're going to be snarky about it, good luck with that, try Google - I'm out.